# JSONP returns unexpected token error :?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am not sure. why this is happening. I hope am doing everything fine. If you guys find any mistake in this, please help me to correct it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'serverurl here',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(data){
      alert(data);  
    },
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/repjt/681/)

Also could you please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Please consult the API docs for wufoo.com service. JSON is not a problem here. That error comes from the API.

Comment: Thanks for quick response :)

Comment: In your url authentication require.

Comment: yes i passed it. Even though i am getting the error